# Python: Problems with functions of imported dll

Tags: python, dll, import

A DLL for a device was imported into Python using ctypes "windll.LoadLibrary"
First, I wanted to use one function of the DLL which is to return the library version.
There came a header file with the DLL in which the function is defined like this:

```
 /**  * \brief  Returns the library version in the format 'AA.BB.CC.DD'
 (e.g. '1.0.0.0').  *  *    OUTPUT PARAMETER  * \param      version        
 Version number of the library  */
 #ifdef __cplusplus extern "C" 
 #endif
     C3_DLL_API void JC_GetDllVersion(char *version);
```

I called the function with `print (str(c3dll.JC_GetDllVersion),"\n")`
But when I run the script I only get this output:

> ('<_FuncPtr object at 0x01A187B0>', '\n')

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: printing just returned the reference pointer, instead of `print (str(c3dll.JC_GetDllVersion),"\n")`, try doing `c3dll.JC_GetDllVersion()`, i am not sure cause it expects an argument too.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't generate any output at all.

Comment: need to print it, `print (c3dll.JC_GetDllVersion())`.

Comment: Ups,I forgot the hyphens after the function's name, but now it just returns: (0, '\n')

Comment: Any other ideas, why this won't work?

Answer (score 0):

So a colleague helped me:
The function "JC_GetDllVersion()" manipulates the paramter it gets handed over and doesn't return a string.
But as a beginner I wasn't aware of that.